# Laravel 10 - Class "PhotoController" does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-10

I'm using Laravel 10, this code is in my web.php file

```
...
Route::resource('photos', PhotoController::class);
....
```

and it produce this list of routes:

```
photos ............................ photos.index › Admin\PhotoController@index  
photos ............................ photos.store › Admin\PhotoController@store  
photos/create ..................... photos.create › Admin\PhotoController@create  
photos/{photo} .................... photos.show › Admin\PhotoController@show  
photos/{photo} .................... photos.update › Admin\PhotoController@update  
photos/{photo} .................... photos.destroy › Admin\PhotoController@destroy  
photos/{photo}/edit ............... photos.edit › Admin\PhotoController@edit
```

it all works fine. Now, I want to protect with authentication all this page, and i use this code

```
Route::prefix('admin')->middleware('auth')->group(function () {
   Route::get('photos', PhotoController::class);
});
```

I got this error:

```
  Target class [PhotoController] does not exist.
```

so i add:      ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Admin')

```
Route::prefix('admin')->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Admin')->middleware('auth')->group(function () {
   Route::resource('photos', PhotoController::class);
});
```

now the site works, but the command php artisan route:list says:

```
 Class "PhotoController" does not exist
```

I have to specify:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PhotoController;
```

The question is.. which is the correct way? use namespace or indicate it with ->namespace()?

Comment: The first way is the correct one (the one without `->namespace`). I think you have something wrong on your `RouteServiceProvider` or the `Kernel.php` file

Comment: Why not check the docs?  I searched for "*Laravel controller*" and about 5s later was looking at an example which answers your question: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#basic-controllers

Comment: I am an idiot, I assumed you where always using `use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PhotoController;` on the top of the file, and then `PhotoController::class` would already have a reference to the correct namespace...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to import the namespace at the top

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PhotoController;
```

that is why Laravel shifted from the old string syntax (It's still supported but no longer best practice for Laravel team):

```
Route::get('/action', 'SomeController@action')
```

to the new syntax (supported since Larave 8):

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Path\SomeController;

Route::get('/action', [SomeController::class, 'action'])
```

Check Laravel controllers documentation examples [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#the-default-route-files) and [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-group-controllers).

The benefits of this are:

- It's clear and more readable
- Ability to use controller namespace so there will be no need to `->namespace('...')` chaining or using it like `'API\SomeController@...`.